# How do I bridge the gap between multiple languages in one project?

Tags: javascript, python

I searched between 10 and 20 questions before asking.

I am in the design stage of my very first project. After some research, I've decided to use THREE.js as the basis for a 3D galaxy map application. Stars and planets will be visible on the map, and their names, detailed information, and the meshes for the different types of stars and planets will be stored on a node.js server.

The application will have a GUI made with Python. There will be buttons to add stars and planets. Clicking them should launch a new menu with the appropriate input fields.

This is my disconnect. What is the missing link for those objects written in javascript being written to a javascript application with Python code? In other words, how do I make components of a project written in different languages communicate?

Comment: Just for clarification: Your server side is entirely JS (node). You use a stand-alone client (Python) which communicates with the server probably via some REST API. Now, you want your python client app to render the loaded data via THREE.js in some kind of 'webview'?

Comment: It will not be a client app in the sense of being downloaded to the user's computer. Everything will be handled in the browser like this http://stars.chromeexperiments.com/ done by a team at Google. The difference will be a GUI I have in the app that allows authenticated users to add planets and stars to the project.

Comment: If it's a webapp running in the browser, how does it then have a GUI made with Python? Could you clarify?

Comment: I guess that is part of what I am asking. Do I have to make a GUI in javascript to be able to add stars and planets?

Comment: Well, your browser (without plugins) can only execute JavaScript. So if you want to create an application which can run in modern browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Edge, you will have to use JavaScript (or compile to JavaScript, but that's a different matter) - or you generate the GUI entirely on the server and serve only a static HTML templates. But since your server is running node, that's also JavaScript.